# Excavator and Marshal badges are being awarded over and over

Tags: bug, status-completed, badges

The excavator has been awarded to... many users just some time ago. What a... bug? Certainly it is, too many unavailable posts :D

Seems to affect **Marshal** and **Excavator**.

> [image: screenshot of many badges in quick succession, all for deleted posts]

Also looks like it's everywhere. SO's got a similar problem a couple of minutes before.

Moreover, I can has THREE X marshals!!!

> [image]

Comment: We're investigating.

Comment: I expect this is going to spread for a while, and to other badges. Further updates in comments here on which sites are affected will probably be noise.

Comment: @Emrakul Reports of affected sites aren't needed, but if there are other badges that have issues, that'd be helpful.

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/325689/2415822

Comment: Here I was, assuming that this was an intentional change to allow it to be earned multiple times for multiples of 500 flags (that matches the number I've just been granted).

Comment: The question on everyone's mind: after all of this is fixed, do we get to keep the badges?

Comment: @JAL Resounding no.

Comment: @JAL Badges that were awarded due to a bug are not badges I would want to keep ;-)

Comment: @animuson There are more old ill-gotten badges in [this query](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/471647/wrongly-awarded-badges).

Comment: @ryanyuyu Where does it mention that the Marshall badge should only be awarded once?

Comment: Yeah looks like just caching to clean up.  My inbox and usercard need updating, but my profile page has the correct badge information (included my most recently earned badge)

Comment: @ᴉʞuǝ I just read the [badge list FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67397/list-of-all-badges-with-full-descriptions#188732)

Comment: @ᴉʞuǝ http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67397/list-of-all-badges-with-full-descriptions#188732

Comment: @ryanyuyu Thanks, not in the actual list of badges..  Perhaps they should add that to the badge page instead of making people track that type of info down.

Comment: @ᴉʞuǝ yeah it's a bit inconsistent in the badge list from the help center.

Answer (score 113, accepted):

We just did a major revamp of how badges are awarded behind the scenes to drastically reduce the load on SQL Server. It now takes advantage of some pre-compute work we're doing to track badge progress in the profile.

However, **I screwed up 2 queries**, specifically the text names of the badges that prevent duplicate awarding. I was thinking to myself earlier "hey, maybe we should pass these in" as part of the rewrite - but it's not *quite* so simple. I'll take another look at this soon but when we're not fighting fires from a SQL Server upgrade. The cardinality changes which hosed some of the bigger badge queries needed urgent attention here, which ended up as a major revamp and introduced the 2 errors reported here.

Apologies for all the bad grants here - that certainly wasn't the intention. Due to *how* badges get tested, it's also not a symptom that shows up locally. If I can change this to a param exclusion passed by the code then things like this become far less likely to happen going forward.

I have cleaned up all achievements and grants associated with the bad code. User badge counts (on user cards and flair) will sync up tonight as part of a regular process.

---

Edit: If you're wondering why I had to address this quickly on the SQL Server front, here's the effect it was having and you can guess when the fix went out:

[image]

Comment: Not a bad mistake to make, we all felt quite happy :)

Comment: Looks like there's some tests you can create. :)

Comment: At least we can see the server will be quite happy from this point forward. This looks like a great fix, after the initial problems have been fixed.

Comment: Is this a problem that only appeared in SQL Server 16?

Comment: @TZHX Yes, in SQL 2016 on compat 130. I have been fighting fires the past 2 days and trying my best not to let users notice anything is happening. I failed here :(

Comment: Can we have some stats on how many people this affected as a payment for our troubles?

Comment: @Quill I don't have unique user counts, but there were 9,102 total grants in play across all sites. 3,420 were on Stack Overflow - the rest were a batch cleanup I wasn't looking at numbers on.

Comment: @NickCraver, which reminds me a question I asked on your blog a week or two ago. You wrote you don't have Unit Test on Stackexchange (besides on Careers), so how do you avoid bugs...?

Comment: @gdoron This wasn't a bug! We just decided to reconsider our recent generosity expansion.

Comment: Just in case you missed it, side effect bug: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/280040/extra-number-of-gold-badges-appearing-in-profile

Comment: Just FYI, this is still not completely fixed on [stats.SE] & "tonight" should have passed. On my userpage, only 1 marshal is listed under the badges tab, but the counts of gold badges at the top of my screen & on my flair / usercard are still incorrectly inflated (21 instead of 19).

Comment: Indeed as @gung said: while the profile page count is now correct card is wrong with a +2 golds for the wrongly awarded medals. :D

Comment: @NickCraver Please take a look at this related bug about cleaning up the awarded badges: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/280089/245360