# Extra number of gold badges appearing in profile

Tags: bug, status-completed, badges, numbers

For a dupe clarification: My question is not a dupe of [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/280023/excavator-and-marshal-badges-are-being-awarded-over-and-over). Instead, my question is like a follow-up of that question. That one mainly reports the re awarding of badges, and not the number, which has not been fixed till now. I am reporting the number, not the re-awarding.

---

I [saw the problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/280023/excavator-and-marshal-badges-are-being-awarded-over-and-over/280028#280028) of the double rewarding of badges. That even happened to me. I was rewarded the marshal badge twice again. Looks like that has been [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed), but still there is a bug left.

I just viewed my profile today, and here is what I saw:

[image]

6 gold badges?? Well I had only 4 of them till yesterday. So I thought it of course must have been because of the double rewarding. But opening my all badges, it looks as if the badges had been reversed, but not the numbers.

I still have only 4 gold badges:

[image]

But the number is wrong. I viewed a few more profiles too, and the same problem was there.

Comment: I think there should be a domain called alwaysblamecachi.ng

Comment: @Braiam You mean to say it's alright for you?? Because when I viewed few  other profiles, like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/users/5299236/kevin-guan), I was able to repro.

Comment: http://shouldiblamecaching.com/ I have this also, I assume it will be recalculated at some point.

Comment: @AlexanderO'Mara I agree. But considering that this was fixed g hours ago, shouldn't the cache have been refreshed?

Comment: Well, I c​​​​​​​​​​​​​​an reproduce. I only have 9 gold badges on [Stack Overflow](//stackoverflow.com), not 11. https://stackoverflow.com/users/5299236/kevin-guan?tab=badges&sort=class

Comment: @Noel I've already linked to that q in my q, and my q is not a dupe of that. That is asking about the rewarding again and again. I know that, and have already read it. I am reporting the number which has not changed. I admit the the badges have been reversed.

Comment: The linked bug caused it, no doubt, question is will it auto-correct itself, or does a dev need to manually tweak the numbers.

Comment: @ShadowWizard I don't know much about the systems of SE, but as per me it will not auto-correct itself. It has been 9 hours since it has been fixed, and I think //shouldiblamecaching.com is out of scope now, because of such a long period already finished.

Comment: Here is the same question on Meta SO: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/325721/gold-badges-count-in-profile-page-not-same-as-the-total-number-of-badges-earned

Comment: Reproducing this as well; also, I still have two phantom gold Marshal badges in my Achievements dropdown. Could be related.

Comment: Yup, I still have two more ghost gold badges on Stack Overflow and the dropdown shows them.

Comment: The linked answer says, it will be corrected as a part of regular process. So, relax.

Comment: @Noel But hasn't "tonight" happened already?

Comment: @Noel Nick said "user cards and flair" - didn't mention profile pages.

Comment: This should get cleared up by a nightly job - lets see what it looks like tomorrow.

Comment: @Oded Okay. I'll wait.

Comment: This sure takes a while to get updated... I still have an inflated badge count.

Comment: I lost my 2 Marshal Badges :(

Comment: @armadillo - nightly. Means it runs once a day. Usually at 3am UTC.