# Tiny profile icons in comments

Tags: feature-request, comments, design, profile-picture

Why not have our profile pictures display next to our name in comments on the side:

> Lorem ipsum etc. etc. - haykam [image: Example in comment on right]

Or on the other side:

> Lorem ipsum etc. etc. - [image: Example in comment on left] haykam

Comment: The weakness of this feature request is, you haven't mentioned any of advantages of having this implemented. The only thing I can think of this is to disambiguate same usernames, but other than that... nothing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While I personally don't want to have this, I found it an intriguing challenge.

So whenever you want to see the avatars in comments, open your browser's console and paste this:

```js
var Position = {"Left": 1, "Right": 2};
var _size = 16;
var _margin = 5;
var _pos = Position.Left;
$(".comment").each(function() {
    var commentObj = $(this);
    var commentUser = commentObj.find(".comment-user");
    var userLink = commentUser.attr("href");
    if (userLink && userLink.length > 0) {
        userLink += "?tab=profile";
        var avatar = $("<span></span>");
        if (_pos == Position.Left) {
            avatar.css("margin-right", _margin + "px");
            avatar.insertBefore(commentUser);
    } else {
            avatar.css("margin-left", _margin + "px");
            avatar.insertAfter(commentUser);
        }
        avatar.load(userLink + " .avatar img", function() {
            avatar.find("img").css({"width": _size + "px", "height": _size + "px"});
        });
    }
});
```

You can customize it a bit:

- Change `_size` to have the avatars appear in a different size.
- Change `_pos` to change where the avatar appears, e.g. changing to `Position.Right` will make the avatars appear to the right of the comment author name.
- Change `_margin` to change the margin between the avatar and user name.

I'm not familiar with browser extensions/plugins, but surely it can also become one to have it apply automatically whenever you visit a post.

Comment: @Peanut first one fixed, see edit. Second one is no repro: http://i.stack.imgur.com/oGGsG.png (I see question asker avatar fine)

Comment: @Peanut cheers! You were right, there was a bug indeed. Forgot that when viewing own profile, the default tab is Activity, which does not contain the big avatar. Forced the link to point to the Profile tab, should be working fine now.

Answer (score 10):

> [image]

<sup>[How does it look without pics?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/280023/excavator-and-marshal-badges-are-being-awarded-over-and-over#comments-280023) *Cleaner.*</sup>

I'd rather not see it.

The first reason I can think of is, it's quite distracting to have a long comments thread with many small images. Unlike the longer answers - you can't see so many avatars on the page. It's uncomfortable to read that.

The other reason is, these avatars would be ridiculously small (because the s=16 does actually downsize the image, not collapse), probably even smaller than you suggested, because otherwise they won't fit.

And it does certainly eat bandwidth, especially if "there still is the 128*128 icon option and we could collapse that".

Comment: @Pea Well, let's simulate that situation ;) maybe I'm exaggerating it.

Comment: @Pea just used the element inspector on the page and manually inserted pics :)

Comment: @nicael manually inserted pics?? Next time use a script...

Comment: @Sha That was something to be done in five minutes, I didn't want to challenge myself with a script for unclear purpose.

Comment: @nicael well, I did. ;-)

Comment: @Sha I've noticed, you have my upvote.

Comment: @Sha waaa, checkmark hijacker :D

Comment: @Peanut not really. First three letters are enough to ping, is easier to write and give a more personal touch to the comment. (in your case the first three letters sounds like... well, you know, so better not use it, but talking about the general case. :))