# Recent activity list error

Tags: bug, android-app, android-app-feed

My recent activity list did show some old Excavator badges today. I thought that maybe it was a temporary hitch in the Android app so went to the main site and saw that the same error was shown in there, too. I even have thought that maybe someone had used my account to edit some posts and examined these sites to see what those edits were and found out that they were referencing to some old edits of mine. Here is the screenshot showing those activities.

[image]

Comment: @Pat while that is the cause, I think those should be removed manually somehow from the app, so not sure marking as duplicate is good.

Comment: @Sha I have the same issue here in the iOS app. Also, there are still in my achievements box on the website. So I still think it is a duplicate, but probably cleanup did not do all cleanup yet.

Comment: Quite the dilemma here, @Pat - on one hand, each should be fixed on its own, probably in a different way, and on the other hand not sure opening new bug report for each is the correct way. Guess I'll just sit on the fence and watch. :)

Comment: @Sha http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/280023/excavator-and-marshal-badges-are-being-awarded-over-and-over#comment909211_280028

Comment: @Pat well, poor Nick is flooded there, I also reported other bug and got no response. (yet.)

Comment: Shouldn't he be asleep now? @Sha

Comment: @Pat if he's asleep for [~20 hours](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/280023/excavator-and-marshal-badges-are-being-awarded-over-and-over#comment909076_280028) I'll be really worried... ;)