# Badge Notification Repeats

Tags: bug, status-completed, badges, notifications

Not sure if someone else has already raised this - I've got eleven notifications that I've received a Caucus badge on English Language Learners.
Perhaps one notification for each community that I'm a member of?

I am a member of the community, and did visit the election. Also, the badge hasn't been awarded more that once (so I think it's just the notification that's at fault).

Note that this seems to happen for other badges, it has been reported for: Caucus, Nice Answer, Enthusiast.

[image]

Comment: I saw the same, but for a different badge. The notifications were just three, but then the badge for that question is not listed between the badge I have.

Comment: Oh no ... not again ... http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/280023/excavator-and-marshal-badges-are-being-awarded-over-and-over

Comment: You also don't have the badge as indicated by @kiamlaluno see [here](http://ell.stackexchange.com/users/37697/haemeternal?tab=badges)

Comment: I'm up to 16 Nice Answer badges here on meta.

Comment: Reproduced: I got two Enthusiast badges on SO today.

Comment: [Same here](http://i.stack.imgur.com/1eq4M.png) - they just keep coming...

Comment: If you have something to add to the post, add a comment, don't edit information with no validity into the post for no reason.

Comment: @Quill I don't understand why you reverted my edit. It's obviously the same bug appearing for various badges. So I added _relevant information_ to the post so that other similar meta Qs can be marked as dupes.

Comment: @rene Yes, I apparently got seven times a badge for the same “Nice Answer”, but it doesn't show up in my profile.

Comment: @yo' If you have something to add to the post, add a comment, don't edit information with no validity into the post for no reason

Comment: @Quill What in the world do you mean by "no validity"?! You mean I'm lying or what?

Comment: I got 5 "Constituent" badges in my inbox (for EL&U), although none of the badges show in my profile / were actually awarded.

Comment: @yo' nobody is saying that, but what you're adding is your observation, not that of the OP. Add comments like everyone else does.

Comment: [Citizen Patrol badge](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/332989/ive-earned-the-citizen-patrol-badge-6-times-bug) report for the same issue.

Comment: I have been 'awarded' the same Great Answer gold badge 3 times so far. This is just *cruelty*!

Comment: I just noticed that while I got a notification that my answer [here](http://meta.askubuntu.com/q/15938/85695) gained me a "good answer" badge [three times](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/283753/203101), the badge itself [hasn't even](http://meta.askubuntu.com/help/badges/24/good-answer?userid=85695) been awarded.

Comment: And also I just got the [revival tag](http://sports.stackexchange.com/help/badges/64/revival) for the second time in few hours and, despite getting the notification, it is not showing in [my profile](http://sports.stackexchange.com/users/11439/fedorqui).

Comment: I already got over twenty notifications about the same “nice answer” badge.

Comment: Yup, [same thing here](http://i.stack.imgur.com/Dx5Py.png)

Comment: @rene Well, it's interesting that [I have done the same thing before](http://meta.stackexchange.com/revisions/280023/7) and nobody complained :-) but ok, I'll do as you wish this time.

Comment: I must have missed that one @yo' ... I'm not always online ;)

Comment: Well, looks like the script that actually award the badge fails, and doesn't rollback the notification that was sent anyway, hence the system try to send the badge over and over again.

Comment: @rene it happens for all badges: for two hours and 20 minutes, not a single badge has been awarded on Stack Exchange. Instead, only notifications keep being sent.

Comment: @ShadowWizard could be caused by an overflow in Jon Skeet's number of badges.

Comment: We're looking into it. Very odd!

Comment: I woke up to this: http://i.stack.imgur.com/QyDkJ.png

Answer (score 25, accepted):

My fault. Isn't it always? We had a problem with badges failing to award last night, so I added some extra logging to capture more info when it stumbled. In the process I accidentally broke something such that it *appeared* to work, but really didn't actually do anything. Deploying the fix now. Sorry folks.

Comment: ....Do I get to keep all these badges?

Comment: @Cai you get to keep the notifications; will that do?

Comment: I'll treasure them.

Comment: Source code or it never happened... :P

Comment: @Cai you never got them. It always was notification-only. So you do “keep all these badges” you have right now, i.e. you won’t lose any.

Comment: #Mistakesthatcausereallyweirdbugs!