# Receiving multiple notifications for the same badge

Tags: bug, notifications, achievements-dialog

One of my answers on Ask Ubuntu meta reached the lofty heights of 25 upvotes and the relevant badge was duly awarded. However, I seem to keep getting the notifications:

[image: achievements menu showing triplicate notification]

Note that only the notification was received in triplicate. The badge was only awarded once.

Comment: Funny thing is that it does not show in the [Good answer badge page](http://meta.askubuntu.com/help/badges/24/good-answer).

Comment: @fedorqui yeah, I noticed that after posting this and left a comment to that effect on the dupe. I have now received yet another notification, but no badge. I'm starting to think there's something like `if(!$badgeAwarded){awardBadge(); notifyUser}` and there's a bug in `awardBadge` so it's stuck in a  loop.

Comment: It really looks like that. I hope they solve this fast, imagine they run out of metal and cannot award anything for the rest of the year :-D

Comment: @fedorqui thing is, nothing has been awarded. They were shooting blanks for three hours.

Comment: @ShadowWizard yep, I have read the main post.