# Achievements listed multiple times

Tags: bug, achievements-dialog

I just got a "Yearling" badge over on Workplace, but the achievements dropdown lists it twice:

[image]

Stays after refresh.

Chrome, Windows 7.

---

#### Update... They're breeding!

Now I have **3** copies:

[image]

Comment: This wouldn't be the first time: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/283748/badge-notification-repeats

Comment: Looks like the workplace meta, not workplace itself. But... yeah.

Comment: Based on the answer from Marc there I assume he should be overwhelmed with log entries now, so he can find the root cause of the bug ...

Comment: Considering you just "created" your Workplace Meta account (by the [Autobiographer badge](http://meta.workplace.stackexchange.com/help/badges/9/autobiographer?userid=7712)), this is just "catching up" to your three Yearlings on main.

Comment: This happened to me today on [meta.se]. I got 3 yearling badged.